# ActiveX code from Visual C++ port to Borland C++ Builder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, activex, c++builder

I have the following code example for Visual C++ which creates an ActiveX object which can then be used.

```
// create a smart pointer for ActiveDSO
    _DActiveDSOPtr activeDSO;  
    HRESULT hr = activeDSO.GetActiveObject(__uuidof(ActiveDSO));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        hr = activeDSO.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ActiveDSO));
        if (FAILED(hr)) 
            _com_issue_error(hr);
    }
```

How should this be ported to Borland C++ builder. I am unsure how it creates ActiveX objects. What should I be looking for to help find the solution, or at least work towards it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to know how to do this, but I haven't used C++ Builder in more than 5 years.

I do remember that C++ Builder comes at ActiveX from a completely different direction, and that code sample won't "translate".

Better to find C++ Builder tutorials and work from there (looking at Deliphi tutorials will also help, they use the same components to wrap the ActiveX objects).

I know this is more "advice" than an answer, but it the best I can do for you.

From a quick search, I found this page that says how to import a specific ActiveX dll, once it's imported I think you use it like any other VCL object.

I hope this helps.

[How to use ActiveX in Borland C++ Builder 4](http://www.ultimaserial.com/bctutor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the menu command Import | ActiveX library?

it generates the sources for you to use the ActiveX to a *.cpp which C++ Builder can use.